# Feature Request: <math> tags for ease of importing a formula from wikipedia into stack exchange

Tags: feature-request, mathjax, markdown

Note that writing `$x^{2}$` produces the mathematical expression $x^{2}$.

I was wondering if sometime in the future the [Math Educators SE](https://matheducators.meta.stackexchange.com) could parse `<math>` `</math>` such that they map to the same token as `$`.

```
<math>x^{2}<math>
```

This would be done to make it easier to re-use formulas from Wikipedia on The [Math Educators Stack Exchange](https://matheducators.meta.stackexchange.com).

Comment: One really *shouldn't* be copy-pasting content from one place to another.  Indeed, it is generally a violation of academic ethics to  do so.  I am not sure why we would want to make it *easier* for users to plagiarize...

Comment: @XanderHenderson This hostile comment makes unwarranted assumptions. There are plenty of valid reasons to copy-paste material.

Answer (score 3):

Running https://npm.runkit.com/mathml-to-latex on the MathML from [this TeX.SE question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85639/i-want-to-convert-mathml-to-latex) produced this:

$$ a < x < a + \left(\delta\right)_{1} \Rightarrow \left|f_{1} \left(x\right) - L_{1}\right| < \frac{L_{1} - L_{2}}{2} \\ \Rightarrow L_{1} - \frac{L_{1} - L_{2}}{2} < f_{1} \left(x\right) < L_{1} + \frac{L_{1} - L_{2}}{2} \\ \Rightarrow \frac{L_{1} + L_{2}}{2} < f_{1} \left(\right. x \left.\right)\textrm{ }$$

It seems to have extra parentheses around $\delta$.

An outline of the code for RunKit (linked above);

```
var mathmlToLatex = require("mathml-to-latex");

const mathml = `<your MathML code here>`;

mathmlToLatex.convert(mathml);
```